# Let $W_{t}$ be a Brownian motion independent of $B_{t} .$ Find the probability $P\left(\int_{0}^{1} e^{t} d B_{t}>\int_{0}^{1 / 2} t d W_{t}\right)$.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Note $B_0$ = 0.

***My attempt***

By Ito's zero mean property an Isometry property we know that:

$E(\int_{0}^{1} e^{t} d B_{t}) = 0 $ and

Variance of $(\int_{0}^{1} e^{t} d B_{t})$ = $\int_{0}^{1} E\left(e^{2 t}\right) d t=\frac{e^{2}-1}{2}$

Similarly:

$E(\int_{0}^{1 / 2} t d W_{t}) = 0 $.

Variance of $(\int_{0}^{1 / 2} t d W_{t})$ is $\left.(\int_{0}^{1 / 2} E(t^2)   dt\right)=\frac{1}{24}$

I know introduce standard normal variable Z and we have:

$\int_{0}^{1} E\left(e^{2 t}\right) d t= \sqrt{\frac{e^{2}-1}{2}} Z$

$\left.(\int_{0}^{1 / 2} E(t^2)   dt\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{24}}Z$

Now we have:

$P\left(\int_{0}^{1} e^{t} d B_{t}>\int_{0}^{1 / 2} t d W_{t}\right)$. = $P(\sqrt{\frac{e^{2}-1}{2}} Z > \sqrt{\frac{1}{24}}Z )$

I am bit stuck now on how to conclude and I am not sure if what I have done is right or wrong.  Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use  the same $Z$ for $(B_t)$ and $(W_t)$ because they are independent. So you have to evaluate $P(\sqrt {\frac {e^{2}-1} 2} Z >\sqrt {\frac 1 {24}} W)$ where $Z,W$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1)$. Since $\sqrt {\frac {e^{2}-1} 2} Z -\sqrt {\frac 1 {24}} W$ is normal with mean $0$ we see that $P(\sqrt {\frac {e^{2}-1} 2} Z >\sqrt {\frac 1 {24}} W)=\frac 1  2$.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy

$P\left(\sqrt{\frac{e^{2}-1}{2} z}>\sqrt{\frac{1}{24}}w\right)$ = 
$1-P\left(\frac{z}w\leqslant \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{24}}}{\sqrt{\frac{{e^{2}-1}}{2}}}\right)$
$=1-\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{24}}}{\sqrt{\frac{{e^{2}-1}}{2}}}\right)$
$=\Phi\left(-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{24}}}{\sqrt{\frac{e^{2}-1}{2}}}\right)$
where $\Phi$ is the cdf of $\frac{z} {w}$.

Is this right?

Comment: You mean $\Phi$ is the cdf of $\frac z w$ right? @codelearner

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. I will edit it. Am I right though?

Comment: It’s not ok, but a linear combination of independant gaussian is gaussian so taking both sides on the left side you have the probability that a gaussian is above 0, what do you think that is ?

Comment: @TheBridge I am not sure what you mean

Comment: @codelearner Is my answer clear now?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How did you get $\frac{1}{2}$ for $P\left(\sqrt{\frac{e^{2}-1}{2}} Z>\sqrt{\frac{1}{24}} W\right)=\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: If $S$ is any continuous r.v. with a symmetric distribution then $P (S>0)=P(S<0)=\frac  1 2$. @codelearner

Answer (score 1):

The first process is described by the SDE
$$dX_t=e^tdB_t$$
The characteristic function solves the ODE
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\hat{P}_X(\omega,t)=-\frac{\omega^2}{2}e^{2t}\hat{P}_X(\omega,t)$$
Therefore
$$\hat{P}_X(\omega,t)=\exp\left\{-\frac{\omega^2}{4}(e^{2t}-1)\right\}$$
which implies $X_1\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\frac{e^{2}-1}{2})$. The second process is described by the SDE
$$dY_t=tdW_t$$
The characteristic function solves the ODE
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\hat{P}_Y(\xi,t)=-\frac{\xi^2}{2}t^2\hat{P}_Y(\xi,t)$$
And its solution is
$$\hat{P}_Y(\xi,t)=\exp\left\{-\frac{\xi^2}{6}t^3\right\}$$
which implies $Y_{\frac{1}{2}}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\frac{1}{3\cdot 2^3}=\frac{1}{24})$. Finally
$$P(X_1>Y_{\frac{1}{2}})=P(V=X_1-Y_{\frac{1}{2}}>0)$$
Since $V \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\frac{e^{2}-1}{2}+\frac{1}{24})$ this probability is $0.5$.

Comment: Thank you! But how do I find the probability 0.5 for $V \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \frac{e^{2}-1}{2}+\frac{1}{24}\right)$ ?

Comment: @codelearner Remember that a Gaussian random variable has mean = mode = median so here the median is 0.

Comment: I am trying to understand it conceptually so correct me if I am wrong. The probability of a Gaussian is area under the curve which $= 1$. Therefore, the probability for a Gaussian random variable to be $< 0$ is 0.5 as the area $> 0 $ is also 0.5, which then = 1? Is my thinking right?

Comment: @codelearner Let $W$ be a Gaussian random variable with mean $\mu$. Then $P(W\leq \mu)=P(W>\mu)=0.5$. In the case above, $\mu=0$. Yes, it's half the area under the curve.